# Show that the intersection of the images of subspaces is a subset of the image of the intersection.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

I'm currently taking Linear Algebra 1, finishing the topic of Linear Transformations (haven't started matrices yet.)

Last lecture, the professor posed the following exercise (among others) on the board:

Let $U_1, U_2 \leq V$ be subspaces of some Vector space $V$ over a field $\mathbb{F}$ , and let $T \in Hom(V,W)$ where $W$ is another subspace over the same field $\mathbb{F}$.

Show that $T(U_1) \cap T(U_2) \subseteq T(U_1 \cap U_2)$

I've tried tackling this several different ways to no avail. I always seem to get stuck at the part where I need to show that for some $w \in T(U_1) \cap T(U_2)$ there exists some $u \in U_1 \cap U_2$ such that $T(u)= w$. I've tried setting a basis for V and using the linearity of T and also setting a basis for $U_1,U_2$.

Intuitively, I can understand why this is true, but so far I haven't found a sound way to show it.

I would appreciate hints aswell as solutions.

UPDATE: It seems that my professor wrote the inclusion the wrong way, making the exercise impossible. Thanks for everyone who helped out either way

Comment: Generally I've seen that set inclusion be the other way around, albeit for functions in general (rather than specifically linear transformations). Don't know of a counterexample offhand, but are you sure you wrote down the exercise correctly?

Comment: @EeveeTrainer I double checked with the prof's lists and that is what was written down. It's possible that he made an error. Honestly I cannot think of a counterexample for either direction of inclusion currently.

Comment: Is there any chance that you're assuming that $T$ is injective?

Comment: @Eeve Trainer T is not injective, but I just confirmed with my prof that the exercise was written wrong and the inclusion is supposed to be the either way. Thanks anyways!